# Export payment in Applications Tab menu of Bill and Adjustments in Acumatica ERP system using webservices api

Tags: c#, web-services, acumatica, erp

I need to export all records in Applications Tab Menu of Bill and Adjustments screen as I did in UI like this screenshot below.

[image]

I already create codes to provide it using this code below.

```
        try
        {
            context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            context.Timeout = 10000000;
            context.Url = url;
            LoginResult login = context.Login(username, password);
            AP301000Content konten = context.AP301000GetSchema();
            //context.AP301000Clear();
            konten.DocumentSummary.Type.Commit = false;
            konten.DocumentSummary.Type.LinkedCommand = null;


            var command = new Command[]
            {
                new Value { Value = "Bill", LinkedCommand = Konten.DocumentSummary.Type },
                new Value { Value = "00123", LinkedCommand = konten.DocumentSummary.ReferenceNbr },
                konten.DocumentSummary.Vendor,
                konten.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr,
                konten.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType
            };

            var result = context.AP301000Export(command, null, 0, false, true);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sCon.getLogout(context);
        }
```

After i debug this code I got records only for VendorCD but Reference Nbr and Doc Type didn't exported. Please refer to this screenshot below.

[image]

please how to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use "every" fields:

```
        var command = new Command[]
        {

            konten.DocumentSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryDocType,
            konten.DocumentSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryRefNbr,

            konten.DocumentSummary.Vendor,
            konten.Applications.ReferenceNbrDisplayRefNbr,
            konten.Applications.DocTypeDisplayDocType
        };
```

Comment: could you update your question with new code (with "every") and result.

Comment: I have solve this problem, I have modified my code in my questions. Thank's for your respon @Kirill Bestemyanov :)